# Could not bind to the port that being exposed(used?) by docker in WSL 2

Tags: c++, docker, sockets

I have a PHP container started by this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    php:
    build: .
    container_name: "my-php"
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9090:9090/udp"
    volumes:
        - ./html:/var/www/html
```

And I want to have a C++ program (running in WSL 2) to communicate with the PHP script inside docker by UDP. But after **docker-compose up**, this code says this port is already in use:

```
#define SERV_PORT   9090

int main()  
{
  int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(sock_fd < 0)
  {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  struct sockaddr_in addr_serv;
  int len;
  memset(&addr_serv, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  addr_serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr_serv.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
  addr_serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  len = sizeof(addr_serv);
 
  if(bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_serv, sizeof(addr_serv)) < 0)  
  {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(1);
  }  
  
  int recv_num;
  int send_num;
  char send_buf[20] = "i am server!";
  char recv_buf[20];
  struct sockaddr_in addr_client;
  
  while(1)  
  {
    printf("waiting recv...\n");
      
    recv_num = recvfrom(sock_fd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_client, (socklen_t *)&len);
      
    if(recv_num < 0)  
    {  
      perror("recv error");
      exit(1);
    }  
  
    recv_buf[recv_num] = '\0';
    printf("server received %d bytes: %s\n", recv_num, recv_buf);
  
    send_num = sendto(sock_fd, send_buf, recv_num, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_client, len);
      
    if(send_num < 0)  
    {  
      perror("send error");
      exit(1);
    }  
  }  
    
  close(sock_fd);
    
  return 0;
}
```

But when I try to run the C++ program before starting the docker container, both the C++ program and the docker container works well.

And when I try to find out which program is taking up the port, the output has neither pid nor program name.

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 9090
udp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                                -
```

Could someone tell me why?

Comment: You don't need to `bind` to actually send messages to a UDP socket.

Comment: I need to both receiving and sending messages, and I tried to receive message without binding, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.
When I tried to change port around for testing, I accidently used a port that not being forwarded by docker, and the whole thing works!

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    php:
    build: .
    container_name: "my-php"
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        # - "9090:9090/udp" (just simply del this
    volumes:
        - ./html:/var/www/html
```

It seems that sending/receiving UDP message between WSL 2 host and docker container doesn't need to open a docker port.

btw, I have no idea why this works thought. (But it does?)